# How to import ROOT in PyCharm. Adding .pyc module to pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, root-framework

I have a problem with importing root into PyCharm IDE (2017.3.1). I have anaconda distribution of python as default, and ROOT is connected to it:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) [GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
>>> import ROOT
>>> print(ROOT.__file__)
/home/balbok/root/lib/ROOT.pyc
```

However, when I open PyCharm I cannot import `ROOT.pyc` (it doesn't see it.) When I try to add path `/home/balbok/root/lib` to interpreter by hand (by going to `Settings > Project Interpreter > Show All` and adding path there), ROOT.py is imported and thus `t=ROOT.TFile()` is not working.
Is there any way of importing `.pyc` as module to Pycharm, or if not, then is there any way of importing ROOT as module (not just `.py` file)?